# CocoaPods Uninstall

Tags: cocoapods

I'm trying to remove an older version of cocoapods.  I've used the terminal command:

```
$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

However, afterwards when I type:

```
$ pod --version
```

I get 0.22.3 in return.

When I try:

```
gem list --local | grep cocoapods
```

nothing is returned.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You may have more luck on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

This command will tell you where the pod binary is installed :

```
which pod
```

You can manually remove it afterwards :

```
sudo rm -rf <path>
```

Answer (score 3):

After `$ sudo gem uninstall cocoapods` write number from choice ex:

```
Select gem to uninstall:
 1. cocoapods-0.34.1
 2. cocoapods-0.34.4
 3. cocoapods-0.35.0
 4. cocoapods-0.35.0.rc2
 5. All versions
> 5
```

It works for me...

Answer (score 0):

1. find out where is the pod installed

```
 which pod
```

2. remove the file
3. remove cocoapod
   s gem specs from /Library/Ruby/Gems/[VersionNumber]/cocoa*

```
    sudo rm /Library/Ruby/Gems/[VersionNumber]/cocoapods*
```

4. reinstall cocoapods

```
    sudo gem install cocoapods
```